# MySQL getting count of a related table

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL's more than a little rusty, and I'm having trouble getting this to work, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I've got three tables:

```
sessions
---------------
id

session_visits
---------------
id | session_id

searches
---------------
id | session_visit_id
```

And I want to get a list of all sessions with the total visits and searches for each sessions, which is linked by the session_visits table. I can get the visits fine, but am having trouble getting the total of searches for each session too.

So far I've got

```
SELECT *,(SELECT Count(*)    
          FROM session_visits    
          WHERE session_id = sessions.id) AS num_visits, 
         (SELECT Count(*)    
          FROM searches    
          WHERE session_visit_id = (SELECT * FROM session_visits    
                                    WHERE session_id = sessions.id)) AS total_searches
FROM sessions
```

Which is failing on every count! Am I going about this the right way or am I fundamentally doing it wrong?

Comment: Why not use join ? also you need to have a `group by`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM session_visits` should be `SELECT id FROM session_visits`. And make sure, that query returns single row, otherway you will need to limit it (for example LIMIT1)

Comment: Rusty? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one query, by joining the 3 tables together, and then use aggregates `COUNT DISTINCT` (to eliminate duplicated) and `COUNT` to get the total number of rows for the child and grandchild rows respectively, grouped by the Sessionid.

```
SELECT s.id AS SessionId, COUNT(DISTINCT sv.id) AS SessionVisits, COUNT(sr.ID) AS Searches
FROM sessions s
  LEFT JOIN session_visits sv
  ON s.id = sv.session_id
  LEFT JOIN searches sr
  ON sr.session_visit_id = sv.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bcb1/3)

(**Edit** : Changed to left outer joins to handle scenarios where there are no visits for session, or no searches per visit)

Comment: That's brilliant thanks - works exactly as I wanted. I was just about to tweak your statement to a LEFT JOIN but you beat me to it. Much obliged.

Comment: Cheers!. I'm guessing `searches.id` is a unique pk of sorts so no need for `distinct`, but obviously repeat the dose if you have more child tables to join in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

query generates error because of column name is not mentioned in query
   **Operand should contain 1 column**

and try with **IN**